# How can I Write this Recursive Function with One Function Only

Tags: python, function, oop, recursion, linked-list

My code is below and I am trying to reverse a linked  list with recursive function and recursively print it. I want to write just one recursive function to traverse linked list instead of using **recursive_print** and **helper_print**. How can I write this recursive code?

Linked List implementation and function are below:

```
class Node:

# Constructor
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:

    # head function
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def reverse_Util(self, curr, prev):

        # If last node mark it head
        if curr.next is None:
            self.head = curr


            curr.next = prev
            return

        # Save curr.next node for recursive call
        next = curr.next

        # update next
        curr.next = prev

        self.reverse_Util(next, curr)

    # This function calls reverse_Util()
    # with previous as Null

    def reverse(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return
        self.reverse_Util(self.head, None)

    # To insert the new node at the beginning of the list

    def push(self, new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    # To print the list
    def printL(self):
        temp = self.head
        while(temp):
            print(str(temp.data) + " -> ",end=' ')
            temp = temp.next

    def recursive_print(self):
        self.helper_print(self.head)


    def helper_print(self,current):
        if current == None:
            return
        print(str(current.data) + " ->",end=' ')
        self.helper_print(current.next)


# Main function
llist = LinkedList()
llist.push(1)
llist.push(2)
llist.push(3)
llist.push(4)


print ("Given linked list")
llist.printL()

llist.reverse()

print ("\nReverse linked list")
#llist.printL()
llist.recursive_print()
```

Comment: Keep in mind that recursion is completely unnecessary for this.  It's yet another example of a fake recursion exercise that makes inappropriate use of recursion.  Any good implementation would be purely iterative.  If you want a real example where recursion makes sense (i.e., where it avoids the need for a stack), write a recursive tree-walking function.

Comment: printing and reversing are two totally different tasks. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: If you use recursion, you won't be able to process lists with more than 1000 nodes. Tom is right. Recursion should only be used when you have a sub-linear stack depth factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve doing this with one method only: you could allow for an *optional* argument that indicates where you currently are in the list and where `None` indicates you are at the start. This approach can be used both for the `reverse` as the `recursive_print` methods:

```
    def reverse(self, prev=None):
        current = prev.next if prev else self.head
        if current:
            self.reverse(current)
            current.next = prev
        else:
            self.head = prev

    def recursive_print(self, prev=None):
        current = prev.next if prev else self.head
        if current:
            if prev:
                print(" -> ", end="")
            print(current.data, end="")
            self.recursive_print(current)
        else:
            print()
```